# Show that any $n$-linked family is subset of one $n$-linked maximal family.

Tags: set-theory

*A $\mathscr{F}$ family of finite subsets in $\mathbb{N}$ is called $n$-linked if for each $X_1,...,X_n\in \mathscr{F}$, $X_1\cap...\cap X_n$ is infinity. Show that any $n$-linked family is subset of one $n$-linked maximal family.*

This is an exercise of my homework. The professor is using the book of Hrbacek and Jech but this is not helping me. Furthermore, I'm search in more books without success. So I wanna give any help here.

Additional literature perhaps confuse me a little more. I would like, if possible, someone explain to me how to solve this in detail because I have no idea how to begin to solve the problem.

(the teacher was on strike and we have no support to solve that problem)

Comment: Are you sure of the question? As it stands there is only one possible n-linked family, $\mathscr F = \emptyset$, (which is of course maximal).

Comment: An intersection of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is never uncountable. I suspect that it should read $X_1\cap\ldots\cap X_n\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Edited. The correct is infinity.

Comment: No, that is not correct either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical use of Zorn's Llama.

Given an $n$-linked family $\scr F$, define $P$ as the set of all $n$-linked families, $\scr F'$ such that $\scr F\subseteq F'$, and order them by inclusion.

It is not difficult to verify that if $C\subseteq P$ is a chain, then $\bigcup C\in P$ is an upper bound for the chain.

Comment: Where you use the definition of n-linked here?

Comment: Well, there's really only one place where we need to do any work whatsoever... So there.

Comment: I need show that $\bigcup C \in P$. Furthermore that this element is an upper bound (so maximal of $P$). This is the first step, right? And here I need use the definition.

Comment: After this, following your steps, I will show that I have an upper bound for the chain. But what I conclude by this? The idea is apply the Zorn's lemma equivalence that tell that if $A$ is an ordered set such that every chain has a upper bound so $a\in A$ has a maximal? Thank you!

Comment: Well, if $\bigcup C$ is an $n$-linked family extending $\scr F$, then it is an element of $P$, and by definition of $\subseteq$ it is an upper bound of $C$. And indeed there you need to use the definition. Zorn's lemma tells you that there is a maximal element in $P$, what sort of object is this maximal element?

Comment: Is the $\bigcup P$? Stay very confuse to me... :(. Furthermore me and my friends dont obtain $\bigcup C\in P$ or that $\bigcup C$ is the maximal of $C$. Can you detail this, please?

Comment: Felipe, $\bigcup P$ is probably not an $n$-linked family. If you managed to somehow add too different sets in different extensions of $\scr F$ (granted it wasn't maximal to begin with), then $\bigcup P$ is just a bunch of finite sets. Moreover $\bigcup C$ is not a maximal element of $C$, who said that it's an element of $C$? It's an element of $P$. To be an element of $P$, namely it is an $n$-linked family extending $\scr F$. And if the elements of $P$ are $n$-linked families ordered by inclusion, what is a **maximal** element in this partial order?